# Return a spilled range from a cell to the last non-empty cell below it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet as follows.

I'm looking for a formula at `E4` that

- contains `D5` (to specify from where the returned spilled range starts)
- returns a spilled range that starts from `D5` and ends at the last non-empty cell below `D5`, which is `G` given the current input.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Sidenote: You opened many question yet you don't really close any of them. It's simple courtesy to let people know; what has worked for you, if it has helped, and close the thread by accepting answers.

Comment: @JvdV I know, I will leave the question open for 1-2 days and see what others say. For this kind of questions, I would like to be exhaustive. Don't worry, I will give feedbacks. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In E4:

```
=D5:INDEX(D:D,MATCH("zzz",D:D))&""
```

[image]

With Office 365 and XLOOKUP:

```
=D5:XLOOKUP("*",D:D,D:D,"",2,-1)&""
```

The two above will find any cell that returns an empty string `""`.  So if in D14, there is `=""` both above will include through D14.

If that is undesirable we can use this formula, that works for any Excel since 2010:

```
=D5:INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(D:D)/(D:D<>""),1))&""
```

One note is that this will be slightly slower than either of the above methods.

Comment: Thank you, `zzz` is not impossible; do you have a better value than `zzz`?

Comment: keep adding more `z` till you know you have more than any consecutive number of `z`s.

Comment: @SoftTimur see edit for more options.

Comment: I just realized that `=D5:INDEX(D:D,MATCH("zzz",D:D))&""` and `=D5:XLOOKUP("*",D:D,D:D,"",2,-1)&""` ignore cells contain numbers.

Comment: Yes, but that was not in your question.  If they are number mixed in, I would go with the Aggregate apporach.

Answer (score 2):

For mixed datatypes, try:

`=D5:INDEX(D:D,MAX(MATCH(CHOOSE({1,2},99^99,"ω"),D:D)))&""`

which will be many times faster than something such as

`D5:INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(D:D)/(D:D<>""),1))&""`

the latter being forced to iterate over more than 2 millions cells, even if there is only data as far as row 100, for example.